# Flash stopped working on Chrome

Tags: 11.10, flash, google-chrome

I upgraded my system to Ocelot from Narwhal and Flash stopped working on Chrome, the plugin is installed on the Software Center, I removed it and installed it thrice but still, no Flash support on Chrome.

Comment: chromium or the official google-chrome browser ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something similar happened to me too during my upgrade. I did the following and everything's working now:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-downloader flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Nice, it worked. :D

Comment: @Jgrimaldos if it worked, it would be nice to mark it as answered

Comment: I can conform this works also in 12.04